# Using RenderScript with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools, renderscript

I am trying to run a simple example on how to use RenderScript from the android NDK. I found this example :

https://github.com/uelordi01/Call_RenderScript_from_NDK

but when I run my app (from Android studio), it doesn't fine some libraries (it seems like).

Here is the logcat output:

```
04-26 16:18:11.705 26653-26653/uelordi.android.hellocomputendk_rs 
E/RS Dispatch: Couldn't initialize dispatchTab.ScriptInvokeIDCreate
04-26 16:18:11.705 26653-26653/uelordi.android.hellocomputendk_rs V/rsC++: 
libRS.so init failed!
04-26 16:18:11.705 26653-26653/uelordi.android.hellocomputendk_rs W/linker: 
libRSSupport.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffef5 arg 0x37720
04-26 16:18:12.018 26653-26859/uelordi.android.hellocomputendk_rs 
E/RenderScript: Couldn't load libRSSupportIO.so
04-26 16:18:12.034 26653-26859/uelordi.android.hellocomputendk_rs 
E/RenderScript: Unable to open shared library 
(/data/data/uelordi.android.hellocomputendk_rs//lib/librs.mono.so): dlopen 
failed: library "libRSSupportIO.so" not found
04-26 16:18:12.034 26653-26859/uelordi.android.hellocomputendk_rs     
E/RenderScript: Unable to open system shared library     
(/system/lib/librs.mono.so): (null)
04-26 16:18:12.034 26653-26653/uelordi.android.hellocomputendk_rs E/rsC++: 
Internal error: Object id 0.
```

(The renderscript file name is mono.rs)

I think I am supposed to add some libraries somewhere (libRS.so, libRSSupportIO.so) but I have no idea where and how and WHY (since the exemple is supposed to work by himself)

this error happens on the following line:
    sc->forEach_root(inputAlloc, outputAlloc);

**side question:**

I looked over the internet but didn't find much (nothing up-to-date). Renderscript is still a thing in 2017, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joy of android developpement. I found the solution! I simply had to change:

```
minSdkVersion 19
```

to:

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

to be honest, I have no idea how to explain this. If anyone has an explanation, that would be great!

Comment: Which release of NDK are you using?

Comment: This seems to be gradle-plugin bug. Instead of using "renderscriptNdkModeEnabled true", I recommend you using ndk-build for using RenderScript NDK. Example: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/tests/device/rs-cpp-basic/jni/

Comment: I am using NDK 14.0.3770861.

@MiaoWang if I build my renderscript/c++ like this, this will generate a shared library (or static library) right? Then if I want to use it, I just have to add it in my CMakeLists ?

Comment: I believe Android Studio 2.2.3+ has proper support for ndk-build. You can still create / compile your entire project using Android Studio, just choose "ndk-build" for the native (rs/c++) code. And in build.gradle, specify the Android.mk path, like https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master-ndkbuild/hello-jni/app/build.gradle#L16